# Child segmentation fault when doing SOAP request in php 5.1.6

Tags: php, soap, apache

I get a "[notice] child pid 26701 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in apache log when I try to do a simple soap request using standard php soap library.

I'm running php 5.1.6 on Centos 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

**Faiure:**

```
class MySoap extends SoapClient {
    public function __construct($wsdl = null, $options = null) {
        parent::__construct($wsdl = null, $options = null);
        $header = new SoapHeader();
        $this->__setSoapHeaders($header);            
    }
}
```

**Success:**

```
class MySoap extends SoapClient {
    private $_myHeader;
    public function __construct($wsdl = null, $options = null) {
        parent::__construct($wsdl = null, $options = null);
        $this->_myHeader = new SoapHeader();
        $this->__setSoapHeaders($this->_myHeader);            
    }
}
```

That will be all...

Comment: Hi @thaDukeW I get a SoapClient::SoapClient(): Invalid parameters

Comment: @Mikunos how to you initiate the class?